# how can I filter data in a list of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

I have a list of pandas DataFrame.
I need to access to each single element of the list and filtering the column values (for instance I want to create a new list with the filtered values).
This is the code:

```
    path = os.chdir('C:/UsersOneDrive/Desktop/py2convers/psychoflicker-master/src/data/TESTPILOTA1/pythonProject1/Data')
filelist = os.listdir(path)
filelist = sorted(filelist, key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))
print(filelist)

interest = []


for file2 in filelist:
    if file2.endswith('.txt'):
        df3 = pd.read_table(file2)
        interest.append(df3[['Trial Condition','Response']])
        print(interest)
```

This is the output with each element of the list:

```
[     Trial Condition Response
0     Bilateral-Left     True
1    Bilateral-Right     True
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3     Bilateral-Left     True
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97    Bilateral-Left     True
98   Bilateral-Right     True
99    Bilateral-Left    False
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1     Bilateral-Left     True
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3    Bilateral-Right     True
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right     True
98    Bilateral-Left    False
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right    False
1     Bilateral-Left     True
2    Bilateral-Right    False
3    Bilateral-Right     True
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right    False
98    Bilateral-Left     True
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0     Bilateral-Left    False
1     Bilateral-Left     True
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3    Bilateral-Right    False
4     Bilateral-Left     True
..               ...      ...
97    Bilateral-Left     True
98    Bilateral-Left     True
99    Bilateral-Left    False
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0     Bilateral-Left     True
1    Bilateral-Right     True
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3     Bilateral-Left     True
4     Bilateral-Left     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right    False
98   Bilateral-Right     True
99    Bilateral-Left     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0     Bilateral-Left     True
1    Bilateral-Right     True
2    Bilateral-Right     True
3     Bilateral-Left     True
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right     True
98   Bilateral-Right     True
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0     Bilateral-Left     True
1     Bilateral-Left     True
2    Bilateral-Right    False
3     Bilateral-Left    False
4    Bilateral-Right    False
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right     True
98   Bilateral-Right    False
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1    Bilateral-Right    False
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3    Bilateral-Right     True
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right     True
98   Bilateral-Right     True
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1    Bilateral-Right     True
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3     Bilateral-Left     True
4     Bilateral-Left    False
..               ...      ...
97    Bilateral-Left    False
98   Bilateral-Right     True
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1    Bilateral-Right    False
2     Bilateral-Left    False
3    Bilateral-Right     True
4     Bilateral-Left     True
..               ...      ...
97    Bilateral-Left    False
98    Bilateral-Left     True
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0     Bilateral-Left     True
1    Bilateral-Right    False
2     Bilateral-Left    False
3     Bilateral-Left     True
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97    Bilateral-Left     True
98    Bilateral-Left    False
99   Bilateral-Right     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1    Bilateral-Right     True
2     Bilateral-Left    False
3    Bilateral-Right     True
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97    Bilateral-Left     True
98   Bilateral-Right     True
99    Bilateral-Left     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1     Bilateral-Left    False
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3     Bilateral-Left    False
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right     True
98    Bilateral-Left     True
99    Bilateral-Left     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right    False
1    Bilateral-Right     True
2     Bilateral-Left     True
3    Bilateral-Right    False
4     Bilateral-Left     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right     True
98   Bilateral-Right    False
99   Bilateral-Right    False
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1    Bilateral-Right    False
2    Bilateral-Right     True
3    Bilateral-Right    False
4    Bilateral-Right     True
..               ...      ...
97   Bilateral-Right     True
98    Bilateral-Left     True
99    Bilateral-Left     True
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns],      Trial Condition Response
0    Bilateral-Right     True
1     Bilateral-Left     True
2    Bilateral-Right     True
3    Bilateral-Right     True
4    Bilateral-Right    False
..               ...      ...
97    Bilateral-Left    False
98   Bilateral-Right    False
99   Bilateral-Right    False
100              NaN      NaN
101              NaN      NaN

[102 rows x 2 columns]]
```

I need to filter the data of the first column (Trial Condition) for each element of the list. I only want to filter the data for Trial Condition = Bilateral Left.

How can I do that?

Comment: try using a lambda function such as df['Trial Condition ']=df.apply(lambda x: x = 'Bilateral left ')

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
path = os.chdir('C:/UsersOneDrive/Desktop/py2convers/psychoflicker-master/src/data/TESTPILOTA1/pythonProject1/Data')
filelist = os.listdir(path)
filelist = sorted(filelist, key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))
print(filelist)

interest = []


for file2 in filelist:
    if file2.endswith('.txt'):
        df3 = pd.read_table(file2)
        interest.append(df3[['Trial Condition','Response']])
        print(interest)

for df in interest:
    print(df.set_index('Trial Condition', append=True, drop=False).xs('Bilateral-Left', level=1))
```